# Как лучше развернуть MongoDB на трех виртуалках

Tags: mongodb

Здравствуйте, уважаемые коллеги!

Решено использовать MongoDB в реальном проекте.
Проект небольшой, нагрузка относительна невелика.
Есть три железных машины, на каждой отведено по виртаулке под базу.
Подскажите:

1. Возможно ли развернуть схему шардирования с реплика-сетами с учетом таких ресурсов?
2. Насколько безопасно поднимать mongo на тех же виртуалках, где расположены и ноды Galera (MySQL)?

Answer (score 1):

> Возможно ли развернуть схему шардирования с реплика-сетами с учетом таких ресурсов?

Да, главное, чтобы реплики и шарды могли подключиться друг к другу по сети.